# webpack v5 ignoring vendor dll

Tags: webpack, webpack-4, webpack-5

I'm now into the painful task of upgrading all our JS stack. I updated every lib, except one: webpack v5 which is causing a heap of problems. I can't really post all my webpack config its a complex and big project. The issue I'm having is related with this error:

You should not use `<withRouter(withReducer(EpicInjector)) /> outside a <Router>`. I've replace with a simple `<Switch><Route>` ... to simplify the code, but same error with  and that's when barely starting the root app.js:

```
const render = (messages, appComp) => {
      ReactDOM.render(
        <Provider store={store}>
              <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
                <CookiesProvider>
                  <Switch>
                      <Route><div>hello</div></Route>
                  </Switch>
                </CookiesProvider>
          </ConfigProvider>
        </Provider>,
        MOUNT_NODE,
      );
    };
```

It looks like pretty obvious when you search for it, but remember that everything works perfectly well with webpack v4. It trickle down to having 2 instance or react-router, but I think its more than that. When using webpack-bundle-analyzer to see my packages, I saw that my vendor package is almost the same which is good news. But when looking at my app package, its differs a lot. First, webpack v4 creates a 0.chunk.js of about 12mb (I'm in dev) along with an app.js of 6mb. When I check references, all react-router ref are in my vendor dll.js which is exactly what I want. On webpack v5, I get the app.js of 11mb, and a ugly chunk named: vendors-node_modules_formatjs_intl-pluralrules_locale-data_en_js-node_modules_formatjs_intl-p-638766.chunk.js of 15mb (wow that's ugly as hell). No ref to vendor dll.js except a mention of 21k to it in the analyser (it's supposed to be at least 30mb if I look at the generated file) so that's what is going on. It ignore vendor completely.

Webpack config are almost the same except for:

```
optimization: {
  moduleIds: 'named',
  emitOnErrors: false,
},
```

and node with fs: 'empty that was replace by:

```
  fallback: {
    fs: false,
    crypto: require.resolve("crypto-browserify"),
    path: require.resolve("path-browserify"),
    vm: require.resolve("vm-browserify"),
  },
```

Other are very small details in the configs. I'm using the webpack.DllConfig and DllReferencePlugin just like before (it did not change really from what I read). It generating the dll manifest and the vendor is approx. the same as before, but the main build is ignoring it completely even with the reference plugins pointing at it. So when I load everything in the browser it's loading my vendor, chunk and app, and boom react-router complain (its not to blame, I have multiple react-router instance!).

I'm searching, what could be wrong and trying all the possible webpack options, but still stuck after a long while and need some help.

Thanks a bunch.

Comment: found the problem: using new webpack.DllPlugin with name and path in v4, did not change in v5. Guess not, I noticed the manifest was very small in v5 compare to v4. So I try putting entryPoint: false (its default to true normally). And I got the same behavior as before and no more strange router error. My chunk file is still name wierdly, wonder if I can change that, since I depend on that name on a post build script later on. And its freaking huge compare to v4. 6mb vs 32mb. Lost nearly 2 day because of that and I'm not finish yet!